# Regular expression is not valid

Tags: java, regex

this is my json from which I want to delete the date value.

```
      {
        "mCheckInTime": null,
        "mCheckOutTime": null,
        "mLateArrivalTime": "2017-09-14T18:00:00.000+05:00",
        "mNumberOfBeds": 0
      }
```

And this one is the coresponding regex

```
    String valueRegex = "^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}\\+\\d{2}:\\d{2})$";
    String message = message.replaceAll(valueRegex, "");
```

And when I run this code, it does nothing.
Anybody please help me in this issue, what is wrong here?

Comment: aren't you redefining `String message = message.replaceAll(valueRegex, "");` ? shouldn't compiler cry ?

Comment: @Mritunjay thats probably what he means with `code does nothing` lol

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `^` (start) and `$` (end) meta-characters from your regular expression:

```
String message = "{\n" +
                "  \"mCheckInTime\": null,\n" +
                "  \"mCheckOutTime\": null,\n" +
                "  \"mLateArrivalTime\": \"2017-09-14T18:00:00.000+05:00\",\n" +
                "  \"mNumberOfBeds\": 0\n" +
                " }";

String regex = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}\\+\\d{2}:\\d{2}";

System.out.println(message.replaceAll(regex, ""));
```

This yields the following output:

```
{
  "mCheckInTime": null,
  "mCheckOutTime": null,
  "mLateArrivalTime": "",
  "mNumberOfBeds": 0
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Robby, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("{");
    sb.append("\"mCheckInTime\":null,");
    sb.append("\"mCheckOutTime\":null,");
    sb.append("\"mLateArrivalTime\":\"2017-09-14T18:00:00.000+05:00\",");
    sb.append("\"mNumberOfBeds\":0");
    sb.append("}");
    String valueRegex = "(\"\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}\\+\\d{2}:\\d{2}\")";
    String message = sb.toString().replaceAll(valueRegex, "null");
```

Result will be:

```
{"mCheckInTime":null,"mCheckOutTime":null,"mLateArrivalTime":null,"mNumberOfBeds":0}
```